# Get screen coordinates of an object by specific latitude and longitude (android)

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, augmented-reality

I have an augmented reality application in android and using metaio SDK as library. in my appplication i placed a 3d object metaioman at given latitude and longitude at camera preview of 4 sides north, south, east and west. and when i move the device at certain location eg east then the object is shown. and now i want to get the screen coordinate of that 3d object. i googled it but havn't found any thing. what should i do..?

It takes three days searching without stopping and have not found anyone to explain how to solve this problem.